# Multiple tab by using session

Tags: c#, session, tabs

```
public ActionResult MultipleTab(int? SelectedCustomerID)
    {
     Session["SelectedCustomerID"] = SelectedCustomerID;
     return view();
    }
```

I open multiple tabs in browser according to selected customer ID(Multiple Customer can be selected).

**I have a problem with session.**

If i choose multi customers**(more than 1 customer**) I **insert first session data every time**.

How can i solve **multiple tabs problem with using session** or do you have another solution to achieve this in asp.net mvc?

Any Help Will Be Appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use querystrings when you need your customer Id.

For instance

instead of using 
Session["SelectedCustomerID"]

try to use this
Request.querystring["SelectedCustomerID"]

Answer (score 0):

Add your `SelectedCustomerID` to `List` , and add this `List` to Session .

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
myList = (List<int>)Session["SelectedCustomerID"];
myList.Add(SelectedCustomerID);
Session["SelectedCustomerID"] = myList;
```

Comment: How can i know which session is selected ?

Comment: I don't clear what you mean ! Do you want to use `Multiple Session` or `Multiple Session Value like array` ? Tell me more information about your function , And I want to know the above answer is useful for you ? Why you accepted ?

Comment: I open customers in tabs.As instance, i open 5 customer page and if i want to change 3. customer data , i change 1. customer data because of session.

Comment: yes , i edit every customer in one tab it means 5 tab for 5 customer